# c program - specifier errors (print lines) and conflicting types for netpay

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I am getting conflicting types for netPay and then expected specifiers errors within the print function lines.  I have tried many suggestions, but still seem to be missing something here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    //Declare the variables with their data types
    int hoursWorked;
    float wagesPerHour;


    //Prompt user to enter the hours worked with a keyboard
    printf("Please enter the hours worked this week: ");
    scanf("%d", &hoursWorked);

    //Prompt the user to enter their hourly pay rate
    printf("\nPlease enter your hourly pay rate, ");
    printf("enter it in $XX.XX format: $");
    scanf("%f", &wagesPerHour);

    //Declare the variables and date types used to calculate the grossPay and taxes
    /*Calculate the gross pay based on the amount of wagesPerHour entered by the user if hoursWorked is equal to
    or less than 40.  If the hoursWorked is more than 40, then calculate the gross pay for the first 40 hours as
    wagesPerHour hoursWorked and add it to wagesPerHour * 1.5 times the number of hoursWorked over 40*/

    float grossPay;
    float tax;
    int overtime = (hoursWorked - 40);
    float oTWagesPerHour = (wagesPerHour * 1.5);

    if (hoursWorked<=40)
    {
        grossPay = hoursWorked * wagesPerHour;
    }
    else
    {
        grossPay = grossPay + (overtime * oTWagesPerHour);
    }

    /*Calculate the tax amount based on the grossPay amount equal to or less than 600 times the tax rate of 0.15.
    If the grossPay is more than 600, then calculate the tax amount for the first 600 times the tax rate of 0.20*/
    if (grossPay <= 600)
    {
        tax = grossPay * 0.15;
    }
    else
        tax = tax + (grossPay * 0.20);
    }

    float netPay;
    netPay = (grossPay - tax);

    //Print the statements below based on the user input and the calculations for grossPay, tax, and netPay
    printf("\nYou entered %d as the hours worked this week and $%.2f as your hourly pay rate.", hoursWorked, wagesPerHour);
    printf("\nGross Pay:\t $%.9f", grossPay);
    printf("\nTaxes Paid:\t $%.9f", tax);
    printf("\nNet Pay:\t $%.9f", netPay);

    return 0;

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAcF0.png)

Comment: Please paste the errors as text into the question itself and not as an image or link to an image.

Comment: Fix your indentation and you should find the problem. On line 45 `else` should be `else {` as there is a closing `}` two lines down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an opening curly brace here:

```
    if (grossPay <= 600)
    {
        tax = grossPay * 0.15;
    }
    else
        tax = tax + (grossPay * 0.20);
    }
```

There is no `{` after the `else`, so the closing curly brace that follows is actually ending the function.  This causes the declaration of `netPay` to be a file-level declaration.  The assignment that follows then produces an error since it's outside of a function.

Just add a `{` after the `else` to fix it.